# SQL Edition, serverproperty

Tags: sql

I am trying to find all the sql installations in our network.

I found more than 100 machine names which has sql installation.

I tried to connect to those machines via client tool, but was not able to. This may happen either I do not have the rights or it may be a client installation.

How can I know what version, edition or basic details about the sql installed in those machines.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you find them if you can't connect to them? What do you mean "client installation"?

Comment: xp_cmdshell 'osql -L'

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin rights on the systems to read the registry but not SQL rights, this powershell script works well:

[How do I check for the SQL Server Version using Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587077/how-do-i-check-for-the-sql-server-version-using-powershell)

I would change the registry key that it looks at for the version from "Version" to "PatchLevel" though if you wanted to know exactly what version it was running, not just the last servicepack.

Answer (score 0):

For internal auditing of your SQL installations (especially when they are so many) you should seriously consider [Microsoft Assessment and Planning (MAP) Toolkit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd537566.aspx). If you have never used it before you will wonder why not!